# wso2 carbon - deploy to servicemix / fuseesb

Tags: wso2, apache-servicemix

My company has decided on fuseesb as their ESB platform.   However, some of the carbon functionality would be useful to us.  For example, the carbon components provide a nice structure for creating backend service components and front end ui components.  Would it be possible to deploy carbon on top of an existing karaf/felix based container such as fuseesb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. We ourselves have successfully deployed carbon on top of Karaf runtime some-time ago.

If you are using Carbon 4.x.x then to expose HTTPService you can use the default shipped tomcat bundle. If you are using Carbon 3.x.x then you have to use Jetty OSGi bundle(not shipped by default) to get the HTTPService in your runtime.

Just to give an idea, Carbon uses embedded tomcat as the servlet container. All the admin services call usually depends on servlet transport (there can be exceptions).

All in all, you can do this, but keep in mind that this is a advanced usage of carbon and ClassLoading issues are on your way and you have to solve those. :)

HTH